# Point Azure Website URL to Another Azure Website

Tags: redirect, azure, azure-web-app-service

- I have 2 azure websites - two separate projects
- I now have 2 URLs:

  - `myazurewebsite.azurewebsites.net`
  - `myazureblog.azurewebsites.net`
    -
- I also have a custom domain, `mysite.com`, which is pointing to `myazurewebsite.azurewebsites.net`.
- Azure will only let me add the custom domain to one of my websites, not both, so the blog site won't let it be accessed using the custom domain.
- **What I want is when you go to `mysite.com/blog` for that to
  actually show the contents of `myazureblog.azurewebsites.net`.**

Can this be done? Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Can you create subdomain blob.mysite.com and point it to myazureblog.azurewebsites.net?

Comment: Right. I know I can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using ARR (Application Request Routing).  See this blog post for more details and an example which roughly matches yours: http://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/

Basically, you create a rewrite rule which forwards all traffic to mysite.com/blog to myazureblog.azurewebsites.net. The client's browser will still show mysite.com/blog, which I assume is what you want.

Comment: Thanks. We'll try this.

Answer (score 1):

We tend to prefix our domains to point them to different azure sites.

E.g www.mysite.com and blog.mysite.com

You cant do it like your attempting with the subdomain.

My two cents

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible, think this way, what if you add google.com to your site with url like mysite.com/google ? people will think google is created by you if that works.